# Publish suddenly trying to publish to Azure web service

Tags: azure, web, service, publish

[this is what it should be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vDYi7.png)
[this is what it is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5G6KY.png)
I Publish my web site as a step to deploying a code change.  All of a sudden, it's trying to publish to Azure web service.  Earlier versions are still publishing as web site correctly.  The only change made that would affect it was upping to version to 4.6 but that was done weeks ago and I have published many times since.  It's a web application in Visual Studio 2017 Community.

I looked at earlier versions of the application to see if any difference jumped out.  I also Google'd the problem.

I need to see the 4 steps to a regular web publish when I right click on Publish Web App, not the publish to Azure web service

Comment: Please edit your question to include more details (screenshots, output from your publish step, etc). Right now it's unclear what could be happening and what, exactly, you're running into.

Answer (score 0):

I found out what my problem was - I had inadvertently at some time in the past month deleted the AppData - which wasn't necessary for running locally, apparently, but is used for Publish
I restored the folder from source control and it worked